# Guess the Quote Game

Tags: python

I am planning to make a game based on a quote list I have been collecting this year with my friends. The list collected has the format "quote - person".

Can someone help me with splitting the quote from the person if I added all the quotes to a single array eg

quotes = ["quote1 - person1", "quote2 - person2", "quote3 - person3"]

Would it be possible for me to split and append the quotes and persons in order to separate arrays so that when I run the program and someone makes a guess after seeing the quote all id need to do is compare the positions in the array and check if they match the inputted person.

If you need me to explain anything further drop me a comment I know it may be a wrongly explained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be better to store the information in a dictionary, which is a list of key-value pairs. In this case the keys would be the quotes and values the person to whom they are attributed. You can build this by doing:

```
split_quotes = (quote.split(' - ' , 1) for quote in quotes)

quote_dict = {q[0] :q[1] for q in split_quotes }
```

EDIT: As Serge Ballesta noted, this doesn't work if 2 persons have the same quote. You could either maintain a list of pairs as suggested:

```
quote_person_list = [(q[0], q[1]) for q in split_quotes]
```

or maintain a list of possible persons for each quote using a `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
quote_dict = defaultdict(list)
for q in split_quotes:
    q[0] = quote
    q[1] = person
    quote_dict[quote].append(person)
```

and check for membership in this list.

Comment: Nice, except that if 2 persons have the same quote, the second will overwrite the first... A list of pairs is more tolerant to that.

Comment: So if it was in dictionary format all id need to do to check the person attached to the quote is run q[quote] to then output whoever the quote belongs to

Comment: @SergeBallesta Good point. Should I leave the offending mistake or edit it over?

Comment: @You can leave the initial dict as you have added a list of pairs and explained why. Depending on the actual use case either could be the most appropriate.